# How to solve C&C Zero Hour LAN connection issues?

Tags: networking, command-and-conquer-generals

I want to play C&C Generals Zero hour with my brother through a direct connection between a desktop PC and a lap top. The connection establishes without any problem until the game starts. then my brother's progress bar fills completely and he enters the game. But in my lap top only my progress bar fills and my his never fills. So the game stops an a disconnection menu with a countdown appears.
we play every other games through this connection type.
I tested this solutions but didn't work:
Run as administrator on Win XP SP 3
Completely turn off Fire wall and add exception or inbound/outbound rule for both Generals.exe and game.dat
Increasing the countdown timer of disconnection menu.

Win 10 - x64